# How to implement a counter of current depth of \input

Tags: counters, input

Suppose `first.tex` contains `\input{second.tex}` and `second.tex` contains `\input{third.tex}`.

I would like to have an automated **input depth counter** whose value is `0` when used inside `first.tex`, `1` inside `second.tex` , and `2` inside `third.tex`. It should increase when `\input` is used and decreased on completion of the input.

How can I implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pifont} 
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\newcounter{InputDepth}

\let\oldinput\input
\def\input#1{\stepcounter{InputDepth}\oldinput{#1}\addtocounter{InputDepth}{-1}}
\begin{document}
\theInputDepth

\input{first}

\theInputDepth

\input{second}

\theInputDepth

\end{document}
```

`first.tex`:

```
\theInputDepth
```

`second.tex`:

```
\theInputDepth

\input{third}
```

`third.tex`:

```
\theInputDepth
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have a recent (after 2020-10-01) release of LaTeX, you can use the new hook mechanism.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-first}
This is first: \theinputdepth

\input{\jobname-second}

Again: \theinputdepth
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-second}
This is second: \theinputdepth

\input{\jobname-third}

Again: \theinputdepth
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-third}
This is third: \theinputdepth
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{inputdepth}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \AddToHook{file/before}{\addtocounter{inputdepth}{1}}%
  \AddToHook{file/after}{\addtocounter{inputdepth}{-1}}%
}

\begin{document}

This is main: \theinputdepth

\input{\jobname-first}

Again: \theinputdepth

\end{document}
```

[image]

The hooks are set at begin document in order to avoid spurious settings of the counter. Not a big deal, though, you can just set the hooks in the preamble; there will be other settings to the counter, but the state will be 0 at the beginning of the document.